# VB.net Passing data between 2 child mdi

Tags: vb.net, mdichild

Can someone provide me with an example please?

Scenario is:

```
 **FORM1** = MDIPARENT
FORM2 = CHILD
FORM3 = CHILD
```

`FORM2` is opened by a menu on MDIPARENT
`FORM2` has a text box - CompanyNameText
next to this textbox there is a button which opens `FORM3` containing a list

What I m trying to achieve is for the user to select a company name from the list in `FORM3` and their selection to show up in `FORM2's` `Companynametextbox`

I've tried :-

```
FORM3:-  

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim formChild2 As AllocateCallBack = DirectCast(Me.MdiParent.MdiChildren(1), AllocateCallBack)
    formChild2.ReceiveValue(SelectTextBox.Text)
    End Sub
```

FORM2:-

```
Public Sub ReceiveValue(ByVal value As String)
    CompanyNameTextBox.Text = value.ToString
    Me.Activate()
    Me.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

But I am getting message Nullreferenceexception` was unhandled.

I've confirmed that the `SelectTextBox` has a value prior.

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code to the button in FORM2 which open FORM3.

```
Dim frm3 As New FORM3()

If frm3.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Me.DoWhatYouWantWithThisValue(frm3.SelectTextBox.Text)
End If
```

When the user select a company from the list in FORM3 you must set:

```
Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
```

Comment: Thats fantastic, thank you for your swift response, on final question. I would like to dock form 3 into form 1, however I can't keep form 3 as a third child as im now getting this error :- Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog.

Comment: I answered with the simplest solution to your problem: if you use ShowDialog there is no need to dock FORM3 to FORM1. If you want to have FORM2 and FORM3 always opened there is another solution but implies a lot more work.